# Get the correct location of a user to display on the screen

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, get, openweathermap

Okay, so this is the javascript that I am using [Link](https://github.com/KanteLabs/Local-Weather/blob/master/main.js) . The issue that I am having is that the code displays Earth for the user's location instead of the actual city. And if I change the value of

```
$(".currentLocation").html(city);
```

to

```
$(".currentLocation").html(data.name);
```

instead of a location I just get a blank.

Comment: Have you tried the response with your browser? Seems like your lat and lon are zero. See: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=0&lon=0&mode=JSON&units=imperial&appid=9815c2fc2b5f1abd1a9ced35afe57d77

Comment: Yeah I am using the chrome tools to debug and I don't understand how my lat and lon values could be zero when it is able to detect my location weather wise but not display the actual location. Because it is raining right now and my application updated to show that it is raining but it's still not showing my locaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because you are calling $get instead $.get() in freegeoip request.

Also change the last line to use the getLocation()

```
$(function() {
  getLocation();
});
```

Comment: I changed it to $.get() and nothing changed. On top of that I tried switching both the city and data.name values and still nothing changed.

Comment: Seems you are not getting the latitude and longitude correctly from the freegeoip. Please check your response for that request and see what it returns. Also are you even calling the getLocation function anywhere?

Comment: Oh no I am not calling the function anywhere. I think the weather link is using the lat and lon values that are initialize at 0 instead of the ones that get changed by freegeoip. So how can I get it to recognize the ones that are changed by freegeoip.

Comment: Well you could initialize them as null values and then just check before calling the openweather. You should also handle errors from the openweather and freegeoip requests and show them to the user if there is any.

Comment: It worrks now I made a careless mistake I didn't realize that you wanted me to call getLocation first and then have that call my weather app. Everything is working perfectly thanks for the help